# How to trade multiple equities at once using Ibrokers in R

Tags: r, algorithmic-trading, interactive-brokers, ibrokers

Using the Ibrokers account I know how to place a  trade with one ticker which , in the example below I place a trade with "DAL"

```
library(IBrokers)
tws=twsConnect(clientId = 1,host = "localhost", port = 7497 )
contract=twsEquity(symbol = "DAL", exch = "SMART" )
order=twsOrder(action = "BUY", totalQuantity ="10", tif = "OPG" )
placeOrder(twsconn = tws, Contract = contract, Order = order)
```

However I am interested in trading multiple tickers  at once for example how can I place an order to buy "DAL" and  "AAL". How can I put multiple orders into IBrokers in R?

Comment: Hey guys I Could really use some help here is there any way I can clarify the question over here .

Comment: Have you tried just running the last 3 lines again(with new values)?  You may want to switch to a newer API.  The R package is no longer updated.

Comment: @Brian thank you for responding I know how to place an order for one stock using Brokers package the example I gave here was the DAL ticker however I would like to know how to trade multiple tickers at once

Answer (score 0):

I doubt your code even works now.  To place another order just place another order.  Note that they must have separate ids and the ids have to increase every order.

```
library(IBrokers)
tws=twsConnect(clientId = 1,host = "localhost", port = 7497 )

id <- tws.reqids(1)

contract=twsEquity(symbol = "AAL", exch = "SMART" )
# give an order id
order=twsOrder(id, action = "BUY", totalQuantity ="10", tif = "OPG" )
placeOrder(twsconn = tws, Contract = contract, Order = order)

# increment id
id <- id+1
contract=twsEquity(symbol = "DAL", exch = "SMART" )
order=twsOrder(id,action = "BUY", totalQuantity ="10", tif = "OPG" )
placeOrder(twsconn = tws, Contract = contract, Order = order)
```

I don't think that code will work.  The defaults for order look to be `LMT`  with a price of 0.  You may want to try `orderType = "MKT"`.  Check the documentation for IBrokers.

I would suggest using a different API, it doesn't look like you have used the R package much so it's not a big deal to switch.  It probably won't work for much longer.  I think it is unsupported and the API has changed since the last update.